# Unable to use drag Drop in radtreeview

Tags: radtreeview

I have binded all data to `RadTreeView` but unable to use drag-'n-drop. I used four properties as

```
IsDragDropEnabled="True" 
IsDropPreviewLineEnabled="True"
AllowDrop="True"
IsDragPreviewEnabled="True"
```

and I want to drop an item within same tree. But it doesnt work.

Comment: Could you provide more relevant info, what does not work?

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a bit of info here : http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/raddraganddrop-events.html

But I'm also having trouble with the tree view.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick read of [this telerik article](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-drag-and-drop-overview.html), drag-drop seems to be working quite well for me.

```
<telerik:RadTreeView ... EnableDragAndDrop="true" OnNodeDrop="MyTreeView_NodeDrop">
```

EnableDragAndDrop and OnNodeDrop seem to be the two vital pieces to getting it working, but weren't in your list of attributes you tried.  HTH

Answer (score 1):

```
 <telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="treeView1" IsDragDropEnabled="True" Margin="2,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedSectionList, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SectionTemplate}" IsEditable="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomSectionList, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="2">
```

Now in the code behind

You have to fire event

In Constructor

```
this.treeView1.AddHandler(RadDragAndDropManager.DropQueryEvent, new EventHandler<DragDropQueryEventArgs>(OnDropQuery), true);
```

Then

```
 private void OnDropQuery(object sender, DragDropQueryEventArgs e)
    {
        RadTreeViewItem destinationItem = e.Options.Destination as RadTreeViewItem;
        object source = this.GetItemFromPayload<object>(e.Options.Payload);
        object target = destinationItem != null ? destinationItem.Item : null;
        DropPosition position = destinationItem != null ? destinationItem.DropPosition : DropPosition.Inside;

        if (source != null && target != null)
        {
            Section sourceSection = source as Section;
            Section targetSection = target as Section;
            Question sourceQuestion = source as Question;
            Question targetQuestion = target as Question;

            if (sourceQuestion != null)
            {
                try
                {

                    if (sourceQuestion != null && targetQuestion != null && object.ReferenceEquals(sourceQuestion, targetQuestion))
                    {
                        sourceSection.Questions.Remove(sourceQuestion);
                        targetSection.Questions.Add(sourceQuestion);
                        e.QueryResult = false;
                        return;
                    }

                    if (targetQuestion != null && position == DropPosition.Inside)
                    {
                        sourceSection.Questions.Remove(sourceQuestion);
                        targetSection.Questions.Add(sourceQuestion);
                        e.QueryResult = false;
                        return;
                    }

                    if (position != DropPosition.Inside && targetQuestion == null)
                    {
                        sourceSection.Questions.Remove(sourceQuestion);
                        targetSection.Questions.Add(sourceQuestion);
                        e.QueryResult = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {


                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.QueryResult = false;
            return;
        }
        e.QueryResult = true;

    }
```

This is it. You will be able to drag and drop.